# Loop timer with PHP

Tags: php

I have a `WEBVTT` file connect with a video, the video length is about 120 minutes. The thumbnail tooptips of the video is running every second, which mean `120*60=7200 secs.`

How to convert 7200 secs to `WEBVTT format(hh:mm:ss.ttt)` with php loop function? Example:

```
00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:01.000
00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:02.000
00:00:02.000 --> 00:00:03.000
00:00:03.000 --> 00:00:04.000    
and so on...
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure that your question is clear...

Comment: If you are intending to update a tooltip via PHP, you may be approaching this from the wrong perspective. PHP is server-side, and you would need something like Javascript to update a tooltip.

Comment: @Fiarr nope, i am not updating the tooltips, i need to loop the timer in php file. e.g: for($i=0;$i<7200;$i++) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`date()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // To fix some timezone problems

$start = 0; // 0h
$end = 7200; // 2h
$output = '';

for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++){
    $output .= date('H:i:s', $i).'.000 --> '.date('H:i:s', $i+1).'.000'.PHP_EOL;
}

echo $output;
```

Note that if $limit reaches 86400 it will start from 0 again.

Comment: Hi Hamza, the result is always starting from 1 hour: 01:00:00.000 --> 01:00:01.000 how to fix this? thanks.

Comment: @ Hamza the result is staring from 2 hours: 02:00:00.000 --> 02:00:01.000 and ended at 3 hours 02:59:59.000 --> 03:00:00.000. any idea?

Comment: @richard Try the edited code, it's impossible that it started from 2 hours. 3600 seconds = 1h

Comment: Hi Hamza, yup, i've tried your new codes above. It's starting at 02:00:00.000 --> 02:00:01.000 and ended 02:59:59.000 --> 03:00:00.000.

Comment: @richard Try to put `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` on top of your code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28203/discussion-between-richard-and-hamza-dzcyberdev)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think PHP is the right tool here.  Sounds like Javascript is probably what you're after if you want to display this on the screen for your users.

For PHP, you can use the date function

```
function secondsToWebvtt($seconds) {
  //set the time to midnight (the actual date part is inconsequential)
  $time = mktime(0,0,0,1,2,2012);
  //add the number of seconds
  $time+= $seconds;
  //return the time in hh:mm:ss.000 format
  return date("H:i:s.000",$time);
}
```

With Javascript, I would use a function like this

```
 var seconds = 0;
 function toTime() {
    var time = new Date("1/1/2012 0:00:00");
    var newSeconds = time.getSeconds() + seconds;
    var strSeconds = newSeconds + "";
    if(strSeconds.length < 2) { strSeconds = "0" + strSeconds; }
    var hours = time.getHours() + "";
    if(hours.length < 2) { hours = "0" + hours; }
    var minutes = time.getMinutes() + "";
    if(minutes.length < 2) { minutes = "0" + minutes; }
    var dispTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + strSeconds + ".000";
    return dispTime;
  }

  function getTime() {
     var time = toTime(seconds);
     //do something with time here, like displaying on the page somewhere.
     seconds++;
  }
```

And then use setInterval to call the function

```
 setInterval("getTime",1000);
```